# Should I still use .Net App Domain for plugins?

Tags: .net, appdomain

I'm currently planning to develop a software which should be able to load plugins in Form of assemblies (with special access restrictions).

I searched the Internet for solutions in .Net and came up with App Domain. I looked into it and it seems like it's what I searched for. So I spoke with a developer about it but he told me to not use App domain because it's deprecated. I tried to find whether it real is but wasn't successful with it yet.

Question is simply:

**Is App Domain deprecated?
If so what are the alternatives? 
Should I consider a different approach if there ain't any?**

PS:
Specs are that assemblies are load during runtime and also unloaded during runtime.

Comment: What sort of app are you running? Desktop? Mobile? Web? Cross-platform?

Comment: It would be cross platform @Kir :)

Comment: Do the plugins need to be isolated from the main memory code? If not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

Otherwise, use .net core and IAssemblyLoadContext

Comment: Thanks for this idea :)! .NET Core is a reliable solution too @Kir